# How can i get the favicon url from a website url using flutter

Tags: flutter, url, favicon

assume someone gives me the URL of google. now I need to find the favicon URL of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most ways you can just add `favicon.ico` to the sites urls, for example https://google.com/favicon.ico, but sometimes it won't work, so you can use [favicon](https://pub.dev/packages/favicon) library:

```
var iconUrl = await FaviconFinder.getBest('https://stackoverflow.com/');
print(iconUrl!.url); // http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking for a direct favicon URL can do this using the Google S2 converter.

Here is the syntax: `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=DomainName`

Example: `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://stackoverflow.com/`

Note: You will not get the highest-quality image but quick around for showing favicon of URL in Flutter

Comment: That's brilliant! You can modify the link to improve the quality, see the link you will receive if you use the example mentioned above: `https://t2.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=https://stackoverflow.com/&size=16`. As you can see it ends with 16, if you change this to 50 the size of the favicon will be increased and so will the quality.